# Django: Is it possible to retrieve a set of related objects from multiple nested levels?

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have the following models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='bs')
```

If I want to retrieve the set of `B`'s that a specific `A` has, I do the following:

```
a = A.objects.get(pk=[whatever])
a.bs.all()
```

Now, If I add the following model:

```
class C(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name='cs')
```

How can I get all `C`s that a specific `A` has? I tried:

```
a = A.objects.get(pk=[whatever])
a.bs.cs.all()
```

But it doesn't work. Is this possible? If it is, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
cs = C.objects.filter(b__a__pk=[whatever])
```

Comment: I figured this out for the other end of the relation, but from the one I've asked is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can, but it would have to be multiple database queries.

Comment: You mean something similar to what @yuvi posted?

Comment: Yes.. But i would _not_ do it that way at all. If the queryset has 50 objects, it is 50 calls to the database.

Comment: Alright, I've understood. So I'll stick with the other end :)

Comment: @RobL It's not too bad. It makes total sense that when looking for C objects you'd filter on C objects. I absolutely agree with karthikr

Comment: @RobL - `C.objects...` is the django-ic way of doing it. I dont know why OP is looking for that alternative.

Comment: @karthikr, Yes, I know. But it would be nice to have the option of making one query to get As and Cs together.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
[b.cs.all() for b in A.objects.get(pk=[whatever]).bs.all()]
```

Or the more appropriate manner, through the C object like this:

```
C.objects.filter(b__a__pk=[whatever])
```

Comment: Isn't there something shorter and more intuitive (something similar to what I've tried and didn't work)?

Comment: Yes, using `C.objects.filter` is simpler. You're looking for C objects so filtering on them is the most intuitive and straightforward way